# How do I validate a date format with python?

Tags: python, datetime, validation

I'm a Software Development student, and currently stuck on validating a date format with Python. I'm currently learning validations and can't really find anything that quite answers the question for what I want to do.

This is the code I want to verify:

```
InvDateStr = input("Enter the invoice date (YYYY-MM-DD): ")
InvDate = datetime.datetime.strptime(InvDateStr, "%Y-%m-%d")

if InvDate == "":
        print("Invoice date cannot be blank. Please re-enter.")
else:
    break
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You can use exceptions to catch when date is invalid, for example:

```py
import datetime

InvDateStr = input("Enter the invoice date (YYYY-MM-DD): ")

try:
    InvDate = datetime.datetime.strptime(InvDateStr, "%Y-%m-%d")
    print("Date valid")
except ValueError:
    print("Date invalid")
```

Prints:

```
Enter the invoice date (YYYY-MM-DD): 2003-02-29
Date invalid
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't look like this worked, unless I did something wrong? 

This is the code I used:

 InvDateStr = input("Enter the invoice date (YYYY-MM-DD): ")
    InvDate: datetime = datetime.datetime.strptime(InvDateStr, "%Y-%m-%d")

    import datetime

    InvDateStr = input("Enter the invoice date (YYYY-MM-DD): ")

    try:
        InvDate = datetime.datetime.strptime(InvDateStr, "%Y-%m-%d")
        print("Date valid")
    except ValueError:
        print("Date invalid")


and this is the error: 

(in next comment)

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/keyinstudent/PycharmProjects/Lesson13/QAP3/main.py", line 12, in <module>
    InvDate: datetime = datetime.datetime.strptime(InvDateStr, "%Y-%m-%d")
  File 

(continued in next comment)

Comment: "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/_strptime.py", line 568, in _strptime_datetime
  tt, fraction, gmtoff_fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
File"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/_strptime.py", line 349, in _strptime
    raise ValueError("time data %r does not match format %r" %
ValueError: time data '1990.03.30' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d'

Comment: Actually, I have it working! I commented out my first two lines of code, and just used the code you provided. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

```
InvDateStr = input("Enter the invoice date (YYYY-MM-DD): ")
try:
    InvDate = datetime.datetime.strptime(InvDateStr, "%Y-%m-%d")
except:
    print("Provided date format is wrong")
```

Alternatively, you can use **parse** method of **dateutil.parser**

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
InvDateStr = input("Enter the invoice date (YYYY-MM-DD): ")
try:
    InvDate = parse(InvDateStr)
except ValueError as e:
    print(e)
```