# How to allow (accept) multiple Date formats?

Tags: python, oop, datetime-format, python-datetime, gdelt

I have some Date formats that i can accept **YYYYMMDDHHMMSS** or **YYYYMMDDHHMM** or **YYYYMMDDHH** or **YYYYMMDD**. I want to check if the Date is in these formats, otherwise print an Error message or catch some error. I tried the achieving this using RegEx. It got really messy and it also matches if the format looks as follows: **YYYYMMDDHHMMSS*_someWord***.  i used `re.match()` and `re.FindAll()`, which behaved as described and that wasn't what i wanted. My code though looks like this but honestly does't work.

```
_date ='201909010900'
regex = re.compile("[1-2][0,9][0-9]{2}[0,1][0-9][0,1,2,3][0-9][0,1,2][0-9][0-5][0-9][0-5][0-9]")
_date = re.findall(regex, _date)
print(_date)
match = re.match(regex, _date[0])
if (match):
     print(_date)
else:
    regex = re.compile("[1-2][0,9][0-9]{2}[0,1][0-9][0,1,2,3][0-9][0,1,2][0-9]")    
    _date = re.findall(regex, _date)
    match= re.match(regex,_date[0])
if (match):
    print(_date)
else: 
    regex = re.compile("[1-2][0,9][0-9]{2}[0,1][0-9][0,1,2,3][0-9][0,1,2][0-9][0-5][0-9]")
    _date = re.findall(regex, _date)
    match= re.match(regex,_date[0])
    
if (match):
    print(_date)        
else: 
    regex = re.compile("[1-2][0,9][0-9]{2}[0,1][0-9][0,1,2,3][0-9][0,1,2][0-9][0-5][0-9][0-5][0-9]")
    _date = re.findall(regex, _date)
    match= re.match(regex,_date[0])
if (match):
    print(_date)
else: 
    print("Invalid date, the format has to be YYYYMMDDHHMMSS or YYYYMMDD or YYYYMMDDHHMM or YYYYMMDDHH")
```

My question is how can i Pythonic and regarding Clean Coding and OOP Principals achieve this. I saw [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74091035/how-do-i-validate-a-date-format-with-python) and was thinking if writing [multiple Try and one Catch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17322208/multiple-try-codes-in-one-block) or some how fix that code. which doen't look like the *Best Practice* to me.

How can i achieve this?

Comment: Maybe of interest that dateutil.parser will correctly parse many date formats and raise an error for unknown formats [link](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html)

Comment: If the expected `date` parameter is to be a valid date format for your list, when would the passed value contain some unexpected characters? Does the value come from a user or system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found one solution as described here. We can use the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53967369/4575197) to check for multiple date format, and return the result then we can check if that's what we wanted or not.